# Show that the orbit $OX$ under an action is the set of matrices in $\mathrm{Mat}_{n×n}(\mathbb{R})$ whose row space is the same as $X$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that the group $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ acts on the set of $n×n$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ via $A·X = AX$, for any $ A \in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and for any $X \in \mathrm{Mat}_{n×n}(\mathbb{R})$ but stuck on going on from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may consider these matrices as the corresponding operators with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Then 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{range}(AX) &= \{w\in\mathbb{R}^n:w = AXv\text{ for some }v\in\mathbb{R}^n\} \\&= \{w\in\mathbb{R}^n:A^{-1}w = Xv\text{ for some }v\in\mathbb{R}^n\} \\&= \{u\in\mathbb{R}^n:u = Xv\text{ for some }v\in\mathbb{R}^n\} \\&= \mathrm{range}(X),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where the third  "$=$" is because $A$ is an isomorphism ($A^{-1}$ is surjective) of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Hence an element $Y$ in $OX$ has the same row space as $X$.

Conversely, if $\mathrm{range}(Y) = \mathrm{range}(X)$, then there exists an isomorphism $\hat{A}$ of $\mathrm{range}(X)$ such that $\hat{A}:Xv\mapsto Yv$. You may check this is indeed an isomorphism, which is easy. Then we can extend $\hat{A}$ to an isomorphism $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $AX=Y$.